# Use monospaced font for axis labels in ggplot2 with png output

Tags: r, ggplot2

I work with genomic data where I want to plot the frequency of trinucleotides.
I want to generate a **png** plot with **ggplot2** and I work on a Linux Centos computer.
As you see in the figure, the x.axis labels are not perfectly aligned as the letters don't have the same size. I want to use a **monospaced** font so I tried the "family" argument to modify the theme but this has no effects.
I have seen and tested many answers using the "extrafont" package with no results as it doesn't seem to work for png outputs.
Is there a simple way of using a monospaced font (e.g. Courier) in ggplot2 with or without using additional package ?

[image]

This is an example of my code so far based on a minimal dataset.

```r
testData <- data.frame(freq = rnorm(10),
                       context = c("ACA","ACC","ACG","ACT","CCA",
                                   "CCC","CCG","CCT","GCA","GCC"))
a <- ggplot(testData, aes(x=context, y=freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.4, fill = "royalblue") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5,
                                   size = 10, family = "mono"),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())
ggsave("test.png",
       plot=a,
       width=2, height=2,
       device = "png",
       dpi = 300,
       type = "cairo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `type = "cairo"` in `ggsave()` is what was causing problems.

Your plot code is correct, when I looked at your plot in RStudio plot window I saw monospaced font as you intended. However, when you saved the plot, the monospace font was replaced with another font, presumably because cairo has it's own font defaults (All of the fonts in your saved plot are serif, even though the ggplot default is sans serif and you never edited the text on your y axis).

I was able to save your plot with monospace font by deleting `type = "cairo"` from `ggsave()`

```
ggsave("test.png", plot = a, width = 2, height = 2, device = "png", dpi = 300)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JanBoyer for answer. I added the `cairo` parameter trying to solve my problem as it was not working without. In the meantime, I tried the same plot in R base and it turns out that for unknown reason, I have a problem with my R installation, as the same R base code works perfectly on another computer.